# External PDFs not refreshing in phonegap app.

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I was hoping to release my very first app using Phonegap today but I have just spotted a big problem - I'm using the Childbrowser on a Mac.

My app was designed to load in external PDFs. But I've notice that after opening my app, and viewing the content, when I disconnect from the internet the content can still be seen. This means that if the external PDFs update my app won't show them.

I don't think it's the Childbrowser that's causing my issue as non Childbrowser pages don't refresh either.

Is there a solution to this?

Many thanks.